# a url that calls products but couldn't located how it's calling products of a catgory

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

The default feature according to my understanding for a

Url : `http://example.net/index.php/products/refrigeration.html`

Path i will look into is : `Backend > catalog > url rewrite Management >` then search for `products/refrigeration.html` in Request path field.

This showed me : `catalog/category/view/id/418`

i.e. Catalog : Module, Category : Controller and ViewAction method. This is ok, i can find this.

But i come across this url **`http://example.net/index.php/products/cat/483.html`** And i can't find this searching on url rewrite management. (i searched for `products/cat/`,`products/cat/483.html`) and i don't see any thing related to this.

So where can i look for this? How is this being routed ? And this url **`http://example.net/index.php/products/cat/483.html`** is populating list of products under that category id `483`.

Answer (score 0):

Check .htaccess for redirects to this url. But in the end it is still probably processed by catalog/category/view method.